# Load product class in custom module prestashop

Tags: module, include, prestashop

I m trying to load product class in a custom made module so that I run the following:

```
 $customized_datas = Product::getAllCustomizedDatas((int)$order->id_cart);
```

My module structure is as follows:

```
class autoWebspace extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'autowebspace';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0';
    $this->author = 'dimitris';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l('webspace creation in plesk');
    $this->description = $this->l('Creates webspace in plesk after purchase');
}


public function install() {
    return (parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder') && $this->registerHook('displayHeader'));
}




public function hookActionValidateOrder($params) {
$customized_datas = Product::getAllCustomizedDatas((int)$order->id_cart);
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that:

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params) {
    $customized_datas = Product::getAllCustomizedDatas((int)$params['order']->id_cart);
}
```

Or you can use `$params['cart']->id` instead.